# I want to print cell value of a column one by one after comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd


data = {'product_name': ['laptop,computer', 'printer,table', 'tablet,mobile', 'desk', 'chair,table'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450, 200]
        }

df_merge = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to print data by using for loop 1st it should come laptop then computer then printer and so on.
for example-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WutGM.png)

I tried below lines of code but not getting what I want.

```
for i in (df_merge.product_name):
print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**USING FOR LOOP**
Code:

```
for i in (df_merge.product_name):
    for s in i.split(','):
        print(s)
```

Output;

```
laptop
computer
printer
table
tablet
mobile
desk
chair
table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.str.split(',')` and then `.explode()`:

```py
print(*df_merge["product_name"].str.split(",").explode(), sep="\n")
```

Prints:

```
laptop
computer
printer
table
tablet
mobile
desk
chair
table
```

---

If you want to *explode* whole dataframe:

```
df_merge["product_name"] = df_merge["product_name"].str.split(",")
df_merge = df_merge.explode("product_name")
print(df_merge)
```

Prints:

```
  product_name  price
0       laptop   1200
0     computer   1200
1      printer    150
1        table    150
2       tablet    300
2       mobile    300
3         desk    450
4        chair    200
4        table    200
```